Coloring a function based on its monotonicity
I have a function f and I would like its graph to be colored based on its monotonicity. Specifically:

Warm colors for the regions where the function is increasing, and
Cool colors for the regions where the function is decreasing.

One idea I had was to color the graph of f based on the values of f′. I wrote the following versions, but the results were disappointing.
f[x_] := x^2 + 20 Cos[x]
m1 = Minimize[f'[x], -10 <= x <= 10, x][[1]];
m2 = Maximize[f'[x], -10 <= x <= 10, x][[1]];
fh1[x_] := (f'[x] - (m1 + m2)/2)/(m2 - m1)
fh2[x_] := (f'[x] - m1)/(m2 - m1)
Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, ColorFunction -> Function[x, Hue[f'[x]]]]
Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, ColorFunction -> Function[x, Hue[fh1[x]]]]
Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, ColorFunction -> Function[x, Hue[fh2[x]]]]

Could anyone help?

Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10},   ColorFunction -> Function[x, Hue[UnitStep[f'[x]]/2]],   ColorFunctionScaling -> False]?

@MichaelE2 This is more or less what I wanted. However, I would prefer to see the shades as well. That is, there should be a gradient between the colors. Also, if at some point the slope is steeper or less steep (greater or smaller value of f'(x)), that should also be reflected in the coloring.

Hue is not good, being cyclic, but often you can scale the argument to a range that it suitable. For instance, Function[x, Hue[0.5 + ArcTan[f'[x]/5]/Pi]]. You can adjust the three numbers to suit. You can increase Pi but I wouldn't decrease it, or different slopes could get the same color.

@MichaelE2 In the f[x_] := x^2 + 20 Sin[x], where I tested it, it colors red even in regions where f is strictly decreasing. It also colors warm regions with increasing behavior.

I'm sure you can figure out how to adjust the range of the color wheel to your liking. Surely you can do a better job of adjusting to what you want than I can guess what you want, no?

For instance, if you want to linearly scale slope in the interval $a \le f'(x) \le b$ to range backwards from blue (Hue[0.7]) to red (Hue[0]), Mathematica can help you with the math: Rescale[#, {a, b}, {0.7, 0}]. ParametricPlot[{s, t}, {s, -1, 2}, {t, 0, 1/2}, ColorFunction -> (Hue[#3] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False] shows the range of Hue and can help you choose the interval of colors. (I tend to linearly scale the angle, not the slope, as suggested by my use of ArcTan. You could use a different nonlinear scaling function, if one better illustrates what you want to represent).

My attempt is those 2 plots. First one by coloring the curve itself:
f[x_] := x^2 + 20  Cos[x]
fPrime = D[f[x], x]; (*Compute the symbolic derivative*)

(*Convert the symbolic derivative into a numerical function*)
fPrimeNum = Function[x, fPrime];

(*Normalizing the derivative to the range[0,1] for use with Hue*)
colorFunction[x_] := Hue[(Sign[fPrimeNum[x]] + 1)/3]

Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, colorFunction[x]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]


My second attempt by coloring the area below the curve:
f[x_] := x^2 + 20  Cos[x]
fPrime = D[f[x], x]; (*Compute the symbolic derivative*)

(*Convert the symbolic derivative into a numerical function*)
fPrimeNum = Function[x, fPrime];

(*Define the color function based on the monotonicity*)
colorFunction[x_] := Hue[(Sign[fPrimeNum[x]] + 1)/3]

Show[Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Black], 
 RegionPlot[y <= f[x], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -100, 150}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, colorFunction[x]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-100, 150}}, BoundaryStyle -> None]]


You can improve the quality by making PlotPoints -> 100 to PlotPoints -> 300, however it takes a bit longer to plot.
Update:
Color scheme 1:
f[x_] := x^2 + 20  Cos[x]
fPrimeNum[x_] := Evaluate[D[f[x], x]];

maxDerivative = MaxValue[{Abs[fPrimeNum[x]], -10 <= x <= 10}, x];

colorFunction[x_] := 
 Blend[If[fPrimeNum[x] >= 0, {LightRed, Red}, {LightBlue, Blue}], 
  Abs[fPrimeNum[x]]/maxDerivative]

Show[Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Black, Exclusions -> None],
  RegionPlot[y <= f[x], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -100, 150}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, colorFunction[x]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 4,
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-100, 150}}, BoundaryStyle -> None]]


Color scheme 2:
f[x_] := x^2 + 20  Cos[x]
fPrimeNum[x_] := Evaluate[D[f[x], x]];

(*Find the maximum absolute derivative value for normalization*)
maxDerivative = MaxValue[{Abs[fPrimeNum[x]], -10 <= x <= 10}, x];

(*Define a color function based on the magnitude and sign of the \
derivative*)
colorFunction[x_] := 
 ColorData["TemperatureMap"][0.5 + 0.5  fPrimeNum[x]/maxDerivative]

Show[Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Black, Exclusions -> None],
  RegionPlot[y <= f[x], {x, -10, 10}, {y, -100, 150}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, colorFunction[x]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 4,
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-100, 150}}, BoundaryStyle -> None]]


Update 2:
Another option, is to put the last color scheme in the curve itself too.
f[x_] := x^2 + 20  Cos[x]
fPrimeNum[x_] := Evaluate[D[f[x], x]];

(*Find the maximum absolute derivative value for normalization*)
maxDerivative = MaxValue[{Abs[fPrimeNum[x]], -10 <= x <= 10}, x];

(*Define a color function based on the magnitude and sign of the \
derivative*)
colorFunction[x_] := 
 ColorData["TemperatureMap"][0.5 + 0.5  fPrimeNum[x]/maxDerivative]

Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, colorFunction[x]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 200, MaxRecursion -> 4, 
 Exclusions -> None]



First of all, thank you for the detailed response. As I mentioned to Michael E2, I would like the coloring to include shades as well. Points with higher f'[x] should be colored warmer, etc. Just like how it happens with the coloring in, for example, a DensityPlot.

@KώσταςΚούδας I edited to include more 2 color schemes. The last one may be what you are looking for.

Thank you very much for the detailed response and the abundance of options!

@KώσταςΚούδας you're welcome!

@KώσταςΚούδας Here's a way to highlight the white parts: Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2], ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, colorFunction[x]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False] /. {{(VertexColors -> c_) :> (VertexColors -> 0.8 c), AbsoluteThickness[t_] :> AbsoluteThickness[t + 1]}, {p_ :> p}} // Show

Here's a way to color the lines produced by Plot, that does not depend on knowing the function used to produce the plot. (I feel I've seen this on this site before. Or maybe I did it. Or maybe I did it for class once. Anyway, I couldn't find it.)
colorFunction = 
 ColorData["Rainbow"][0.5 + ArcTan[#/10]/Pi] &@
   First@Ratios[First@Differences[#]] &; 
Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}] /. Line[p_] :> ({
      colorFunction[#],
      Line[#]} & /@
    Partition[p, 2, 1])


Minus: It doesn't use Hue, but it's not clear in the OP whether that is a requirement.
Another minus: Rainbow is deprecated in some communities. (Not color-blind friendly?) But its range is from cool to warm as desired. Here's a replacement based on Paul Tol's color schemes:
accessibleRainbow = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/8ngJtMtU"]
(*  Blend[{...}, #1] &  *)

You can replace ColorData["Rainbow"] with accessibleRainbow.
It's not much different, but I think it tries to optimize as much as possible contrast/distinctiveness of differences across the range for all.

Thank you very much for the solution! Thanks also for the alternative coloring options!

@KώσταςΚούδας You're welcome! :)

This is the best solution so far

Another alternative is to use ConditionalExpression:
f[x_] := x^2 + 20  Cos[x];
df[x_] = D[f[x], x];
critVals = NSolveValues[df[x] == 0 && -10 < x < 10, x]; 

Plot[{ConditionalExpression[f[x], df[x] > 0], 
ConditionalExpression[f[x], df[x] < 0]}, {x, -10, 10}, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}, 
PlotLegends -> {"Increasing", "Decreasing"}, Filling -> Bottom, 
Epilog -> {PointSize[0.0115], Black, Point[{#, f[#]} & /@ critVals]}]



Use the code by questionor.
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_] := x^2 + 20 Cos[x]
m1 = Minimize[f'[x], -10 <= x <= 10, x][[1]];
m2 = Maximize[f'[x], -10 <= x <= 10, x][[1]];

Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x}, ColorData["TemperatureMap"]@Rescale[f'[x], {m1, m2}]],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Filling -> {1 -> -20}]



Thank you very much for your response!

Based on the comments about shading, maybe you could do something like this:
f[x_] := x^2 + 20 Cos[x];
cf = Function[x, Blend[{Green, Red}, Rescale[Clip[f'[x], {-50, 50}], {-50, 50}, {0, 1}]]]
Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}, ColorFunction -> cf, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]


Adjust the parameters as desired.

Thank you very much for the response! This one works just fine too!
